# Question about heat energy of a mixture

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

How many grams of water at $25\; ^{o}$C must be added to $300\;$g of water at $40\;^{o}$C, for the final temperature to be $30\;^{o}$C? (No heat is lost to the surroundings.)

I tried using the formula Q=mc(T-T0) but I don’t know how to implement it. Please help

Comment: Stackexchange is not a place to ask questions about one's homework, but rather a place to ask questions about phenomena or certain (famous) problems one does not understand. Please do not ask questions about your homework.

Comment: Then why does there exist the tag “homework and exercises”?

Comment: @furfur: Hi. Under specific conditions homework and homework-style questions are allowed. Consult the site policy on this.

Comment: Homework guidance: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Hint: Use conservation of energy (in this case, heat) and conservation of mass, and the heat capacity of water.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is really an algebra problem, since we are mixing like with like, and they didn't even ask in volume!

300g at 40 degrees.   Final temperature 30 degrees. Difference = 10 degrees.
Water added at 25 degrees.  Difference = 5 degrees.

300g × 10/5 = 600 grams 25 degree water.  Total mass = 900 grams.

Comment: Please explain the downvote.  Is this answer incorrect?.